# react dragmove collision not stopped

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

I have been trying to implement a canvas with dragging, which works fine, but I want to prevent certain items on the canvas to overlap or come within a certain distance of a specific item when being dragged. I get till the point where the xy is stopped when an item is colliding with another one, but I can still drag the item over the other.

Here is a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-paper-fmpn58?file=/src/App.jsx

You should see in the console the x y coordinates changes, until you collide items.

Can someone have a look at how to fix that?

Comment: What is setBounceLocation intended to achieve?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat it is the left-top location (red line) of the item being dragged, if those cross the other item (red line) then the x y stopped changing and is the location of of the xy just before it crossed the other line (you can see it changing and stops in the console.log), but I can still drag the item further, which should not be, it should stop at the border of the other element.

Comment: How do you intend to stop the shape from moving? What properties do you set?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, I set the PosX and PosY as position (with value from the locationMap). But do I need to set it on the transformer as well then? since that holds the anchor points for the resizing, etc.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, I was able to set the transformer position (as the element itself does not change it's position). And in the console.log I can see the XY pos of the transformer not changing when the collision happens, but the dragging still happens.

Comment: @lavrton, could you help out?

Comment: Make a snippet of a minimal demo that shows what you need to do.  Then I'll take a look.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, I have the minimal demo here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dry-paper-fmpn58?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx